Running React Native Expo App locally using USB debugging
I'm learning react and i want to debug my app using my android device but i don't want to use the Expo Go app.
Tried these commands as per my research but none of these works:

react-native run-android
error log:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'run'




expo start --localhost --android
error log:
expo : File C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1


expo start --localhost android

Did i miss something during react native or expo installation/setup?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

While you can run and debug your React Native Expo app on your Android device without using the Expo Go app, it's important to mention that the experience is generally better and easier when you use Expo Go. This is due to the integration and simplified debugging tools it provides.
Note: The expo start --localhost --android commands would normally work if you are using the Expo Go app.
